# Craps Game Simulation

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a craps game using javascript. I have pretty much everything working the way its supposed to be, just have to make a few minor adjustments, but the part I am stuck on is creating some type of type function, or possibly using the setTimeout(). I have a .wav file playing the sound of dice being rolled, but what I would like to do is have the text if the user won or lost appear after the sound of the dice being rolled(after the .wav file stops playing the dice rolling sound).

Comment: What are you using to play the sound? Perhaps there is a callback function for when it is done? That is typically how something like this would be handled in JS

Comment: what calls the .wav file?  Put a command to display text at the end of the calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can detect any event about the sound file ending.
You should play the sound, then start a setTimeout function with a hard-coded duration.

Eg:

```
setTimeout(diceRolled,3000); //these are millisecond -> 3 seconds wait

// ..........

function diceRolled(){
//do anything here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the "correct" answer is to use html5 audio and bind to its various events - you can get the file's duration, detect if a sound has finished playing, get its current playback location, etc.

However, it's fairly complicated to use, and I wouldn't recommend it for this purpose or for starting javascripters.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/